# Unable to remove UIProgressView from Super View after "cross" button clicked?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, cocos2d-iphone, uiprogressview

I am stuck in hidden problem. I want to remove all UIProgressView from Superview. I am creating cross button in this way,

```
crossButton = [[CCMenuItemImage alloc] initWithNormalSprite:[CCSprite spriteWithSpriteFrame:[[CCSpriteFrameCache sharedSpriteFrameCache] spriteFrameByName:@"close-bttn.png"]] selectedSprite:nil disabledSprite:nil block:^(id sender)
                                     {
                                         [self hideProgressBarForDownload];
                                         [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:kNotificationInAppLayerClosed object:self userInfo:nil];
                                         [[GameManager sharedGameManager]setCurrentLayer:-1];
                                         [self removeFromParentAndCleanup:YES];
                                     }];
```

While when it is clicked, following methods are call in a hierachy

```
-(void) hideProgressBarForDownload
{
    [[DownloadManager sharedDownloadManager]removeAllProgressbarsIfvisible];
}

-(void)removeAllProgressbarsIfvisible
{
    NSArray * allkeys = [currentDownloads allKeys];

    for (int i = 0; i < [allkeys count]; i++)
    {
        NSString *key = [allkeys objectAtIndex:i];
        DownloadItem * item = [currentDownloads valueForKey:key];
        UIProgressView * progress = item.progressIndicator;
        //progress.hidden = YES;
        if (progress.superview)
        {
            [progress removeFromSuperview];
        }
    }
 }
```

I guess every piece of code is right but don't know why they are not removing.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: remove the if(progress.superview) and see if it works?

Comment: Your code looks reasonable to me too. How are the progress views created and hooked up in the download items? And did you try debugging `removeAllProgressbarsIfvisible`? Does `progress` have any value different from null?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try like this,in button action action method put this code

```
for(UIView *view in self.view.subviews){
        if([view isKindOfClass:[UIProgressView class]]))
            [view removeFromSuperView];
    }
```

Comment: That would work only if all progress views are direct subviews on the very next level of self.view. If the progress view is a subview of a subview then your code as such would not remove them.

Comment: if you are not adding progressbar directly then give yourview.subviews  in the place of self.view.subviews.

Comment: Or search for the progress view subviews in a recursive way.

Comment: Thanks Sunny. Your solution worked and you saved my whole day. Thanks once again. Have a nice day.

Answer (score 0):

Remove all progress bars from a given view:

```
- (void) removeAllProgressBars:(UIView *)view {

    if([view isKindOfClass:[UIProgressView class]]))
       [view removeFromSuperView];
    else 
       for (UIView *subView in view.subviews) 
         [self removeAllProgressBars:view];
}
```

In some other method call:

```
[self removeAllProgressBars:self.view];
```

Although I consider it bad coding style not to use curly breackets on 1-statement-bodies of for and if and else etc.